# Number of Books using MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, sorting

I am working on the library database, which contains the Books and Authors tables.

> Columns of the `Books` table: `id, name, year, author_id`.
> Columns of the
> `Authors` table: `id, name`.
>
> Write a query to get the author names and the number of books they
> have in the Books table.
>
> Note that some authors do not have any books associated with them. In
> this case, the result needs to include their names and have 0 as the
> count. The count column should be called books in the result.
>
> Sort the result by the number of books, from highest to lowest.

```
SELECT A.name AS name, COUNT(B.id) AS books
FROM Authors A
LEFT JOIN Books B ON A.id = B.author_id

GROUP BY A.name
ORDER BY books DESC, A.name;
```

I am getting the result but not expected.
the expected output is:

```
name,books
F. Scott Fitzgerald,3
Jane Austen,3
William Shakespeare,2
Miguel de Cervantes,1
Herman Melville,1
Stephen King,0
Mark Twain,0
```

The output that i am getting is :

```
name,books
F. Scott Fitzgerald,3
Jane Austen,3
William Shakespeare,2
Herman Melville,1
Miguel de Cervantes,1
Mark Twain,0
Stephen King,0
```

Comment: The only difference between your output and the expected output is the order of authors with the same count. The instructions don't say what that order should be, your query puts them in alphabetical order.

Comment: Since any order should be acceptable, your solution should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

As You want to sort it by surname, you can use SUBSTRING_INDEX for this

```
SELECT A.name AS name, COUNT(B.id) AS books
FROM Authors A
LEFT JOIN Books B ON A.id = B.author_id

GROUP BY A.name
ORDER BY books DESC,SUBSTRING_INDEX(`name`, " ", -1)
```

Which gives you

| name | books |
| --- | --- |
| Jane Austen | 3 |
| F. Scott Fitzgerald | 3 |
| William Shakespeare | 2 |
| Miguel de Cervantes | 1 |
| Herman Melville | 1 |
| Stephen King | 0 |
| Mark Twain | 0 |